# Customize haddock comments color

Tags: font-lock, customize, haskell-mode

How can I change the color of the comments starting with `-- |` in Haskell mode?

When I write a comment in Haskell I get a grey face, but when the comment starts with `-- |`, as required by Haddock documentation lines, it takes a green one. I have tried to change the `Haskell Literate Comment Face` to inherit from `font-lock-doc-face` to `font-lock-comment-face`, but it has had no effect over the comments starting with `-- |`.

**Edited:**
Ok. Now I see the problem. The face of these comments is not `Haskell Literate Comment Face`, it is directly `font-lock-doc-face` (?). If I change it, the comments reflect the change. But why is it like this? I would like to change the color of the doc-comments only for Haskell, not globally.

Comment: Using this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1242366/2552681 I have get `font-lock-doc-face`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to change the color of the doc-comments only for Haskell, not globally.

You can combine the buffer-local effects of [Face Remapping](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html) with a mode hook to achieve this. For example, in order to display Haddock comments with the same face as plain comments, you can write something like

```el
(add-hook 'haskell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (face-remap-add-relative 'font-lock-doc-face
                                     'font-lock-comment-face)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume it had no effect, because `font-lock-comment-face` is set to grey too.

Try <kbd>M-x</kbd> customize-face <kbd>RET</kbd> haskell-literate-comment-face <kbd>RET</kbd>

Then disable the check-box "inherit", open the now enabled menu and edit the values at place.

WRT your comment: Looks like a bug. See in haskell-mode-autoloads.el

```
(defface haskell-literate-comment-face '((t :inherit font-lock-doc-face))
```

Maybe editing it there will help. Might require a re-compile than, as the *.elc files --if present-- will be loaded.

Comment: Disabled "inherit". Changed "foreground" to dark_gray, "Saved and set" everything, reloaded .emacs file... and still no changes. I must be missing something.